# why NotificationCenter.observer is not listening to notifications

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Hai guys I am new to iOS development and still learning

I have a three View controllers ,**viewController, SViewController, TViewController**

in **SviewController** I have notification sender.post method on clicking a button

in **viewController, TViewController** viewdidload() methods I have .addobserver() methods

when I click a button on **SViewController** and post the notification

**View Controller**'s selector is executed and not the **TviewController**

I have loaded the **TviewController** in FirstVC i.e **ViewController** viewdidload() method only

since segue performs again a viewdidload() from SviewController to TviewController with another button ,I tried to allocate a completion handler string to global variable so that it value remains same and print it(changed value) when view is loaded again, then I came to know that the completion handler is not at all executing here is the code

**ViewController**

```
import UIKit

extension Notification.Name{
    static var fnote = Notification.Name("fnote")
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fhandle(notification:)), name: .fnote, object: nil)
    
    let storyboad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tvc = storyboad.instantiateViewController(identifier: "1") as! TViewController
    
    let _ = tvc.view
    print(tvc.isViewLoaded)
    
    print("journey")
}

@objc func fhandle(notification:Notification){
    label.text = "Haii welcome to the hyderabad"
}


}
```

**SViewController**

```
import UIKit
var temp:String = "HHH"

class SViewController: UIViewController {

 
 
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .fnote, object: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

**TviewController**

```
import UIKit



class TViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handler(notification:)) , name: .fnote, object: nil)
       
        print(temp)
        print("happy")
    }

   @objc func handler(notification:Notification)
    {
        print("jackson")
        label2.text = "Hurray"
        temp = label2.text ?? "Nothing"
    }
}
```

Can Some one please help me with this

Comment: This is not SwiftUI

Comment: You haven't shown what you are doing with `TViewController`? You instantiate it as `tvc` -- but immediately after the line `print("journey")` it ***goes out of scope***. That is, it no longer exists. Are you trying to add it as a `child` view controller? Are you trying to `present` it? Are you planning on `pushing` to it as part of a navigation controller?

Comment: DonMag I am sorry I just checked .isviewloaded to check whether the view is loaded or not , and print(journey) is used to check whether it is getting printed every time in viewdidload method ,it is not a part of the navigation controller, I loaded the TViewController before the post notification was sent,so that tviewcontroller will listen to it , that what my idea was

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown or explained where / when / how you're going to display the view from `TViewController`, but to explain the *first* thing you're doing wrong...

In this code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
 
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fhandle(notification:)), name: .fnote, object: nil)
    
    let storyboad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let tvc = storyboad.instantiateViewController(identifier: "1") as! TViewController
    
    let _ = tvc.view
    print(tvc.isViewLoaded)
    
    print("journey")
}
```

as soon as `viewDidLoad()` finishes (that is, immediately after the `print("journey")` line), your `tvc` instance of `TViewController` is destroyed. That is, it's dumped from memory and no code inside it can execute, because it no longer exists.

That's called "going out of scope."

So, when you try to post a notification from `SViewController`, there is no `TViewController` in existence so its code is not running to "observe" the notification.

Here is a very simple example of multiple view controllers observing a notification:

[image]

When you `push` from `ViewController` to `TViewController`, you get a new instance of `TViewController` and the original instance of `ViewController` still exists.

When you `push` from `TViewController` to `SViewController`, you get a new instance of `SViewController` and **both** `ViewController` and `TViewController` still exist.

When you tap the "Post" button, `ViewController` and `TViewController` will each execute the func you assigned to observe the notification.

When you then go Back to `TViewController`, you'll see its label text has changed, and when you go back to `ViewController` you'll see its label text has also changed.

Note that if you then push to `TViewController` again, you get a ***new instance*** and its label will be back at its original text.

```
extension Notification.Name{
    static var fnote = Notification.Name("fnote")
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(fhandle(notification:)), name: .fnote, object: nil)
        print("journey")
    }
    
    @objc func fhandle(notification:Notification) {
        print("Got it!")
        label.text = "Haii welcome to the hyderabad"
    }
    
}

class TViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handler(notification:)), name: .fnote, object: nil)
        print("happy")
    }
    
    @objc func handler(notification:Notification) {
        print("jackson")
        label2.text = "Hurray"
    }

}

class SViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var infoLabel: UILabel!
    
    @IBAction func click(_ sender: Any) {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .fnote, object: nil)
        infoLabel.text = "Notification Posted"
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much , I will try to put the image in it ,in your story board you kept the TViewController in the middle between ViewController and SViewController i.e(V,T,S) but my way of presentation is (V,S,T) view,sview,Tview
I wanted the notification to be heard in a controller that hasn't been pushed on the stack , mean to say the future/upcoming view controllers, but later I realised I need to load a TviewController to listen , so I loaded in ViewController only, I thought that I will remain in memory so I don't know the out of scope memory concept as I am still learning , Thank you

Comment: @Sri - OK, then you're misunderstanding the purpose of Posting Notifications. That can be used to **notify existing objects** (classes) that something happened. It can ***NOT*** do anything to objects that are not "alive" -- that is, if you have a view controller class that will be shown *sometime in the future*  this won't help. NotificationCenter is generally used when you have an event / message that you want to distribute to multiple classes that are currently **in use**. You need to do some reading up on ...

Comment: @Sri ... Closures, Delegate / Protocol pattern, setting properties in a class that is *about to be shown*, etc. You should probably forget about `NotificationCenter` altogether for the time being.

Answer (score -1):

```
let storyboad = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tvc = storyboad.instantiateViewController(identifier: "1") as! TViewController
let _ = tvc.view
print(tvc.isViewLoaded)
```

This is not the way to test the notification. Push your "TViewController" controller from the "ViewController" controller. Then post notification from your target controller.

Comment: For that I have to embedded in to navigation controller??

Comment: I hope, your first view controller is already embedded in the navigation controller.

Comment: No, could you tell me if post a notification in second view controller, how could I make all other observers in different view controllers to make listen , with the above method i am not able to do it, by the way I tried using your method also by embedding it not to nav controller it didn't worked

Comment: Make sure, that the view controller should be in the navigation stack in which you have added an observer.